# javascript to overlay a modal popup that is center aligned

Tags: javascript

want to know Simply the javascript to overlay a div on centre of the page.

Just want to use plain java script to show and hide a div **on the center of the page** with "Please wait..." message and disable the background. Also this div shoud show on top of the other content of the page.

My div looks like this

```
<div id='mydiv' style="display:none;" ><img src="myimg.gif" /> Please Wait... </div>
```

On click of a button , I want to show the div content center aligned on the page.

I **do not** want to use jquery,extjs,,etc to achieve this.

I have seen a few examples on the web with lot of other features added to a modal popup, just looking for something simple and clean.The bare minimum JS required to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The div you want to display needs to have an ID:

```
<div id="loaderdiv">
```

Then in your javascript, you display this div with the following code:

```
document.getElementById("loaderdiv").style.display = '';
```

Thats the bare minimum you'll need.

Centering the image can be done using CSS:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-[imgheight/2]px;margin-left:-[imgwidth/2]px">
```

Comment: Thanks bouke, I konw this part -  but how do i center align it and show it on top of the screen is my real query.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="overlay_msg" id="overlay_msg" style="width:350px; height:100px; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:300px; margin-top:20%; visibility:hidden; z-index:201; position:fixed; padding:15px; text-align:center;">
                <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a><br />
        </div><!--overlay_msg-->
        <div class="my_overlay" id="my_overlay" style="background-color:#000000; opacity:.7; position:fixed; z-index:200; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="hideMyOverlay()">
        </div><!--my_overlay-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showMyOverlay()
            {
                document.getElementById('my_overlay').style.visibility='visible';
                document.getElementById('overlay_msg').style.visibility='visible';
            }
            function hideMyOverlay()
            {
                document.getElementById('my_overlay').style.visibility='hidden';
                document.getElementById('overlay_msg').style.visibility='hidden';               
            }
        </script>
```